# Can't load a service for category "ExternalGraphicFactory"

Tags: geotools

I'm using geotools-18.5, with JavaFx in Inteliji IDE.
When I want to create PointSymbolizer from a svg or png image.

```
StyleBuilder builder = new StyleBuilder();
ExternalGraphic extGraphic = builder.createExternalGraphic("file:/home/cuongnv/test.svg", "svg");
```

I build code OK, but when run, I received warning:

> WARNING: Can't load a service for category "ExternalGraphicFactory".
>   Provider org.geotools.renderer.style.ImageGraphicFactory could not be
>   instantiated.

Can someone help me ?

Here is full code:

```
private Style createStyleBuilder(){
        StyleBuilder builder = new StyleBuilder();
        FilterFactory2 ff = builder.getFilterFactory();

        // RULE 1
        // first rule to draw cities

        // define a point symbolizer representing a city
        Graphic city = builder.createGraphic();
        city.setSize(ff.literal(50));
        ExternalGraphic extGraphic =        builder.createExternalGraphic("file:/home/cuongnv/Javafx/GeoTool/geotools_fx_tutorial-master/geotools-fx/src/main/resources/images/console.svg", "svg"); // svg
        city.addExternalGraphic(extGraphic);
        PointSymbolizer pointSymbolizer = builder.createPointSymbolizer(city);
        Rule rule1 = builder.createRule(pointSymbolizer);
        rule1.setName("rule1");
        rule1.getDescription().setTitle("City");
        rule1.getDescription().setAbstract("Rule for drawing cities");
        Rule rules[] = new Rule[] {rule1};
        FeatureTypeStyle featureTypeStyle = builder.createFeatureTypeStyle("Feature", rules);
        Style style = builder.createStyle();
        style.setName("style");
        style.getDescription().setTitle("User Style");
        style.getDescription().setAbstract("Definition of Style");
        style.featureTypeStyles().add(featureTypeStyle);
        return style;

    }

TYPE = DataUtilities.createType(
                    "Dataset",
                    "geometry:Geometry:srid=4326"
                            + ","
                            + "name:String,"
                            + "id:String"
            );
            SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
            GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
            com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x,y));

            featureBuilder.add(point);
            SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);


            DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", TYPE);
            featureCollection.add(feature);

            Style style = createStyleBuilder();
            Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);
            layer.setTitle("New Point");
            mapContent.layers().add(layer);
```

Comment: do you have gt-renderer included in your dependencies? But it is just a warning, do you get the output you expect?

Comment: I have resolved this problem. It required some dependencies. I have add all depends to project, it doesn't show warning. 
But now, I don't get output i expect. Instead of image on map, it only show gray rectangle.

Comment: we need to see more code, is extgraphic null? what is the rest of the style? etc

Comment: I've submit my full code. Please show me my wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the image mime type incorrectly, it should be:

```
ExternalGraphic extGraphic = builder.createExternalGraphic("file:/stuff/ian/geoserver/data/styles/burg02.svg", "image/svg"); // svg
```

and all will work.

**EDIT**

If you are still having issues then try adding this code to the end of the createStyle module and look at the generated SVG, possibly in GeoServer to test it out.

```
SLDTransformer styleTransform = new SLDTransformer();
StyledLayerDescriptor sld = sf.createStyledLayerDescriptor();
UserLayer layer = sf.createUserLayer();
layer.setLayerFeatureConstraints(new FeatureTypeConstraint[] {null});
sld.addStyledLayer(layer);
layer.addUserStyle(style);

try {
  String xml = styleTransform.transform(sld);
  System.out.println(xml);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It's not work. I don't know how to debug ExternalGraphic is right or wrong ?

Comment: that line is the only one I changed in your code and it works for me, can you try with another svg file, try https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/data/release/styles/burg02.svg

Comment: It is still no work for me :(.
I change svg file by png file, output is the same. Is there problem in my file path ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, It work OK with png file, but svg file, it's still no work.

Comment: OK. I've added gt-svg to my project. It work OK. Thanks you very much.